# Ordinal brushing in parallel coordinates in d3 V4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am looking for parallel coordinate visualization in d3.js that has both ordinal and numerical values in d3 V4. I have created a sample http://plnkr.co/edit/TiM6ZsvMTTBhh8ZdMoFQ?p=preview

I am trying to brush the 'name' column as well. It seems there are lots of changes in d3 brush in V4. Also is there a way where I can snap the brushing area in both cases of ordinal and numerical columns.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
   stroke-opacity: .4;  
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-opacity: .7;
}

.brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .3;
  stroke: #fff;

  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  cursor: move;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(1),
    y = {},
    dragging = {};


var line = d3.line(),
    //axis = d3.axisLeft(x),
    background,
    foreground,
    extents;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var quant_p = function(v){return (parseFloat(v) == v) || (v == "")};     

d3.csv("cars.csv", function(error, cars) {
  // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
    //cars[0] contains the header elements, then for all elements in the header
    //different than "name" it creates and y axis in a dictionary by variable name
    console.log("ok");
    dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]);
    x.domain(dimensions);

  dimensions.forEach(function(d) {
    var vals = cars.map(function(p) {return p[d];}); 
    if (vals.every(quant_p)){ 
     y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { 
            return +p[d]; }))
        .range([height, 0])
      }
    else{           
      y[d] = d3.scalePoint()
          .domain(vals.filter(function(v, i) {return vals.indexOf(v) == i;}))
          .range([height, 0],1);}
  })

  extents = dimensions.map(function(p) { return [0,0]; });

  // Add grey background lines for context.
  background = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
  foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // Add a group element for each dimension.
  var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(dimensions)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
      .call(d3.drag()
        .subject(function(d) { return {x: x(d)}; })
        .on("start", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = x(d);
          background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
        })
        .on("drag", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
          foreground.attr("d", path);
          dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
          x.domain(dimensions);
          g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
        })
        .on("end", function(d) {
          delete dragging[d];
          transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
          transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
          background
              .attr("d", path)
            .transition()
              .delay(500)
              .duration(0)
              .attr("visibility", null);
        }));
  // Add an axis and title.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) {  d3.select(this).call(d3.axisLeft(y[d]));})
      //text does not show up because previous line breaks somehow
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9) 
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [8,height]]).on("brush start", brushstart).on("brush", brush_parallel_chart));
      })
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);
});

function position(d) {
  var v = dragging[d];
  return v == null ? x(d) : v;
}

function transition(g) {
  return g.transition().duration(500);
}

// Returns the path for a given data point.
function path(d) {
  return line(dimensions.map(function(p) { return [position(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
}

function brushstart() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}


// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush_parallel_chart() {    
    for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){
        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {
            extents[i]=d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);

        }
    }

      foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
            if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
                return true;
            }
          return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
        }) ? null : "none";
      });
}

</script>
```